# Dungeon Defenders - not picking items and mana?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

In Dungeon Defenders, what happens to items and mana that are not picked between waves and at the end of the level? Are they sold off and divided into player's mana bank, or are they just lost? Is it explained somewhere explicitly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Items that are left on the ground are sold for their mana cost and split between the number of players. The same goes for mana that is not picked up.

Source:
http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Mana

> Items left on the ground at the start of a wave get turned into mana and split between the players.

If you lose the level you don't get the mana that is on the ground, it's lost because you lost the round.

Comment: I find this the best way to do things while playing with friends. We only pick up stuff explicitly better than what we have, then the rest is sold and we all get an even cut. :)

Comment: I know when you have won a level and  you leave to the tavern or next level this also happens. I am not sure what happens if you lose or exit a level earlier... might be useful to add that to the answer if its figured out.

Comment: @James If you lose the level you don't get the mana that is on the ground, it's lost because you lost the round. - Added to answer.

Comment: also one more thing to keep in mind, there is a max item limit cap in DD, on some maps where lots of items will drop, things will start disappearing, and you will NOT get mana for those items.

Comment: Is the amount of mana gained from those items-turned-to-mana the same as you'd get from collecting and selling them?

Comment: @Pete Probably, but you probably should make this a separate question or a comment on an already existing answer. Generally when you "answer" someone's question, you shouldn't be following it with another question, as nobody can reply to your question.

Comment: @James I can confirm that if you exit to your Tavern at the end of a level (after succeeding, but without proceeding to next level, the items on the ground will still be sold and split.

Comment: my issue is the cap on number of items i cant get past feeling like im missing out on mana. for shorter waves that dont have huge amount of drops auto sell is best.

Answer (score 1):

NO.

in the end of the level, yeah the items are sold automatically.  But during the level, there is a item limit for the dropped items and when they reach at the limit; they just disappear. Try to pick all of the items that drop a round and sell them all at the end of the wave. That will bring you more mana.